# improper results in behavioral model in verilog

Tags: verilog

even though there are typing errors, I mainly worried about the case construct executing default statements.

I changed `always @(in1,in2)` to `always @*` and also observed that the arithmetic shift operation is not working properly. I changed the as given below:
now i got correct results.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module simpleBmul(res,in1,in2);
output [15:0] res;
input [7:0] in1,in2;
reg [15:0] res;

reg FF;

initial
begin
    FF=1'b0;
    res[15:0]=16'h00;
end

always @*
begin
    res[15:8]=8'h00;
    res[7:0]=in1;
    FF=1'b0;
    repeat(8)
    begin
        case({res[0],FF})
        2'b00,
        2'b11: ;
        2'b10:{res[15:8]}=res[15:8]-in2;
        2'b01:{res[15:8]}=res[15:8]+in2;
        default:$display("\t\t\terror");
        endcase
        {res,FF}=$signed({res,FF})>>>1'b1;
    end
end
endmodule

--------------------------------------------------------------
ouput:
at time 0   in1=00000000, in2=00000000, res=0000000000000000
at time 21  in1=01011000, in2=00110111, res=0001001011101000
at time 31  in1=00110101, in2=01011001, res=0001001001101101
```

sorry for interruption and thank you for the response

Comment: What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Your `if-else` statement is so strange that I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Glad we could help. If the answer was correct could you accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is intentional or not but you have:

```
  else 
    $display("\t\t\terror");    
    {res,FF}={res,FF}>>>1'b1;
  end
```

As part of you if statment, since you have not used begin end statments the line `{res,FF}={res,FF}>>>1'b1;` is always executed. While learning verilog I would encourage the liberal use of begin end statements as I find this to be the most common type of bug.

You effectively have written this:

```
repeat(8) begin 
  if(({res[0],FF}==2'b00) | ({res[0],FF}==2'b11)) begin
    ; //Missing assignment
  end
  else if({res[0],FF}==2'b10) begin
    res[15:8]=res[15:8]-in2;
  end
  else if({res[0],FF}==2'b00) begin
    res[15:8]=res[15:8]+in2;
  end
  else begin 
    $display("\t\t\terror");    
  end
  {res,FF}={res,FF}>>>1'b1; //Always execute
end
```

NB: I would avoid the use of manual sensitivity lists like `always @(in1,in2)`
replacing with `always @*`.